# Complex XPath - Write an XPath in reference to another element

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath

There is a table. This table is a parent div. This parent div has two children. The first child div is the table header and the second one contains the value of headers.

Parent highlighted in bold and children is highlighted in italics bold.

```
<div class="sc-jgHCyG eZqcrI"> // >>>>>>> Parent div
    <div class="sc-cTkwdZ fFvlhF"> // >>>>>>>>>>>> child div - containing table headers
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi kHBkvh JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="false"
             width="1.8050541516245486">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi fhvIWI JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="false"
             width="7.2202166064981945">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div>Ticket</div>
            </div>
            <div><span class="sc-hTZhsR cQSaWH"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                     aria-hidden="true"><path
                    d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"></path></svg></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi gRDfhj JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="true"
             width="10.108303249097473">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div class="sc-citwmv kajamm"><img draggable="false" src="/static/media/drag-indicator.5c17cc6e.svg"
                                                   alt="drag"></div>
                <div>Date</div>
            </div>
            <div><span class="sc-hTZhsR cQSaWH"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                     aria-hidden="true"><path
                    d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"></path></svg></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi bPRqpN JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="true"
             width="8.664259927797833">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div class="sc-citwmv kajamm"><img draggable="false" src="/static/media/drag-indicator.5c17cc6e.svg"
                                                   alt="drag"></div>
                <div>Customer Name</div>
            </div>
            <div><span class="sc-hTZhsR cQSaWH"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                     aria-hidden="true"><path
                    d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"></path></svg></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi fhvIWI JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="true"
             width="7.2202166064981945">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div class="sc-citwmv kajamm"><img draggable="false" src="/static/media/drag-indicator.5c17cc6e.svg"
                                                   alt="drag"></div>
                <div>Supplier</div>
            </div>
            <div><span class="sc-hTZhsR cQSaWH"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                     aria-hidden="true"><path
                    d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"></path></svg></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi fhvIWI JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="true"
             width="7.2202166064981945">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div class="sc-citwmv kajamm"><img draggable="false" src="/static/media/drag-indicator.5c17cc6e.svg"
                                                   alt="drag"></div>
                <div>Material</div>
            </div>
            <div><span class="sc-hTZhsR cQSaWH"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                     aria-hidden="true"><path
                    d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"></path></svg></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi fhvIWI JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="false"
             width="7.2202166064981945">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div>Quantity</div>
            </div>
            <div><span class="sc-hTZhsR cQSaWH"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                     aria-hidden="true"><path
                    d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"></path></svg></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi fhvIWI JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="true"
             width="7.2202166064981945">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div class="sc-citwmv kajamm"><img draggable="false" src="/static/media/drag-indicator.5c17cc6e.svg"
                                                   alt="drag"></div>
                <div>Status</div>
            </div>
            <div><span class="sc-hTZhsR cQSaWH"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                     aria-hidden="true"><path
                    d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"></path></svg></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi fhvIWI JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="false"
             width="7.2202166064981945">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div>Hauler</div>
            </div>
            <div><span class="sc-hTZhsR cQSaWH"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                     aria-hidden="true"><path
                    d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"></path></svg></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi fhvIWI JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="false"
             width="7.2202166064981945">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div>Field Temp</div>
            </div>
            <div><span class="sc-hTZhsR cQSaWH"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                     aria-hidden="true"><path
                    d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"></path></svg></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi fhvIWI JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="false"
             width="7.2202166064981945">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div>Gross</div>
            </div>
            <div><span class="sc-hTZhsR cQSaWH"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                     aria-hidden="true"><path
                    d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"></path></svg></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi fhvIWI JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="false"
             width="7.2202166064981945">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div>Tare</div>
            </div>
            <div><span class="sc-hTZhsR cQSaWH"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                     aria-hidden="true"><path
                    d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"></path></svg></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi fhvIWI JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="false"
             width="7.2202166064981945">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div>Net</div>
            </div>
            <div><span class="sc-hTZhsR cQSaWH"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                     aria-hidden="true"><path
                    d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"></path></svg></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-cBNfnY sc-eggNIi jHksBY JiLrb align-items-center justify-content-between" draggable="false"
             width="7.2202166064981945">
            <div class="sc-iWFSnp cmuvkJ">
                <div>Max GVW</div>
            </div>
            <div><span class="sc-hTZhsR cQSaWH"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                     aria-hidden="true"><path
                    d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"></path></svg></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div> // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> second child div 
        <div>
            <div class="sc-cOajty bPLPeB d-flex">
                <div title="" width="1.8050541516245486" class="sc-cBNfnY kHBkvh">
                    <div class="mt-2"><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div>
                </div>
                <div title="48701236" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>48701236</div>
                </div>
                <div title="2021-01-03T00:00:00.000-05:00" width="10.108303249097473" class="sc-cBNfnY gRDfhj">
                    <div title="2021-01-03 10:30:00 am">2021-01-03 10:30:00 am</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="8.664259927797833" class="sc-cBNfnY bPRqpN">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="NH 9.5 75G" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>NH 9.5 75G</div>
                </div>
                <div title="24.13" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>24.13</div>
                </div>
                <div title="delivered" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>delivered</div>
                </div>
                <div title="" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div title="90" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>90</div>
                </div>
                <div title="39.39" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>39.39</div>
                </div>
                <div title="15.26" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>15.26</div>
                </div>
                <div title="24.13" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>24.13</div>
                </div>
                <div title="753962" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY jHksBY">
                    <div>753962</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sc-cOajty bPLPeB d-flex">
                <div title="" width="1.8050541516245486" class="sc-cBNfnY kHBkvh">
                    <div class="mt-2"><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div>
                </div>
                <div title="48701235" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>48701235</div>
                </div>
                <div title="2021-01-02T00:00:00.000-05:00" width="10.108303249097473" class="sc-cBNfnY gRDfhj">
                    <div title="2021-01-02 10:30:00 am">2021-01-02 10:30:00 am</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="8.664259927797833" class="sc-cBNfnY bPRqpN">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="NH 9.5 75G" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>NH 9.5 75G</div>
                </div>
                <div title="29.36" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>29.36</div>
                </div>
                <div title="delivered" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>delivered</div>
                </div>
                <div title="" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div title="77" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>77</div>
                </div>
                <div title="43.19" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>43.19</div>
                </div>
                <div title="13.83" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>13.83</div>
                </div>
                <div title="29.36" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>29.36</div>
                </div>
                <div title="96026" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY jHksBY">
                    <div>96026</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sc-cOajty bPLPeB d-flex">
                <div title="" width="1.8050541516245486" class="sc-cBNfnY kHBkvh">
                    <div class="mt-2"><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div>
                </div>
                <div title="48701234" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>48701234</div>
                </div>
                <div title="2021-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00" width="10.108303249097473" class="sc-cBNfnY gRDfhj">
                    <div title="2021-01-01 10:30:00 am">2021-01-01 10:30:00 am</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="8.664259927797833" class="sc-cBNfnY bPRqpN">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="NH 9.5 75G" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>NH 9.5 75G</div>
                </div>
                <div title="14.1" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>14.1</div>
                </div>
                <div title="delivered" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>delivered</div>
                </div>
                <div title="" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div title="34" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>34</div>
                </div>
                <div title="26.25" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>26.25</div>
                </div>
                <div title="12.15" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>12.15</div>
                </div>
                <div title="14.1" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>14.1</div>
                </div>
                <div title="22692" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY jHksBY">
                    <div>22692</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sc-cOajty bPLPeB d-flex">
                <div title="" width="1.8050541516245486" class="sc-cBNfnY kHBkvh">
                    <div class="mt-2"><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div>
                </div>
                <div title="48701233" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>48701233</div>
                </div>
                <div title="2020-12-31T00:00:00.000-05:00" width="10.108303249097473" class="sc-cBNfnY gRDfhj">
                    <div title="2020-12-31 10:30:00 am">2020-12-31 10:30:00 am</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="8.664259927797833" class="sc-cBNfnY bPRqpN">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="12.5MM RECYLE LIME" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>12.5MM RECYLE LIME</div>
                </div>
                <div title="21.44" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>21.44</div>
                </div>
                <div title="delivered" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>delivered</div>
                </div>
                <div title="" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div title="98" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>98</div>
                </div>
                <div title="30.27" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>30.27</div>
                </div>
                <div title="8.83" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>8.83</div>
                </div>
                <div title="11.44" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>11.44</div>
                </div>
                <div title="564054" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY jHksBY">
                    <div>564054</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sc-cOajty bPLPeB d-flex">
                <div title="" width="1.8050541516245486" class="sc-cBNfnY kHBkvh">
                    <div class="mt-2"><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div>
                </div>
                <div title="48701232" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>48701232</div>
                </div>
                <div title="2020-12-30T00:00:00.000-05:00" width="10.108303249097473" class="sc-cBNfnY gRDfhj">
                    <div title="2020-12-30 10:30:00 am">2020-12-30 10:30:00 am</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="8.664259927797833" class="sc-cBNfnY bPRqpN">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="NH 9.5 75G" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>NH 9.5 75G</div>
                </div>
                <div title="29.94" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>29.94</div>
                </div>
                <div title="rejected" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>rejected</div>
                </div>
                <div title="" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div title="68" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>68</div>
                </div>
                <div title="38.91" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>38.91</div>
                </div>
                <div title="8.97" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>8.97</div>
                </div>
                <div title="29.94" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>29.94</div>
                </div>
                <div title="741980" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY jHksBY">
                    <div>741980</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sc-cOajty bPLPeB d-flex">
                <div title="" width="1.8050541516245486" class="sc-cBNfnY kHBkvh">
                    <div class="mt-2"><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div>
                </div>
                <div title="48701231" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>48701231</div>
                </div>
                <div title="2020-12-29T00:00:00.000-05:00" width="10.108303249097473" class="sc-cBNfnY gRDfhj">
                    <div title="2020-12-29 10:30:00 am">2020-12-29 10:30:00 am</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="8.664259927797833" class="sc-cBNfnY bPRqpN">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="NH 9.5 75G" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>NH 9.5 75G</div>
                </div>
                <div title="20.41" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>20.41</div>
                </div>
                <div title="pending" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>pending</div>
                </div>
                <div title="" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div title="" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div title="31.99" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>31.99</div>
                </div>
                <div title="11.58" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>11.58</div>
                </div>
                <div title="20.41" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>20.41</div>
                </div>
                <div title="31702" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY jHksBY">
                    <div>31702</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sc-cOajty bPLPeB d-flex">
                <div title="" width="1.8050541516245486" class="sc-cBNfnY kHBkvh">
                    <div class="mt-2"><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div>
                </div>
                <div title="48701230" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>48701230</div>
                </div>
                <div title="2020-12-28T00:00:00.000-05:00" width="10.108303249097473" class="sc-cBNfnY gRDfhj">
                    <div title="2020-12-28 10:30:00 am">2020-12-28 10:30:00 am</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="8.664259927797833" class="sc-cBNfnY bPRqpN">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="Democompany" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>Democompany</div>
                </div>
                <div title="12.5MM RECYLE LIME" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>12.5MM RECYLE LIME</div>
                </div>
                <div title="17.51" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>17.51</div>
                </div>
                <div title="voided" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>voided</div>
                </div>
                <div title="" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div title="" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div title="29.99" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>29.99</div>
                </div>
                <div title="12.48" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>12.48</div>
                </div>
                <div title="17.51" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI">
                    <div>17.51</div>
                </div>
                <div title="973479" width="7.2202166064981945" class="sc-cBNfnY jHksBY">
                    <div>973479</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to find out all Gross (10th header column) values. Position Gross is always changing. Per solution I have in mind I need to write an XPath in reference to letter "Gross". So that even if its position changes, XPath will work.

This is the XPath I wrote: `//div[text()='Gross']/../../../following-sibling::div//div[@class='sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI']` and it should give 7 cells (elements) but it gives all cells.

How can I write a unique XPath that will give me a list of all 7 Gross values (table cells)?

```
39.39
43.19
26.25
30.27
38.91
31.99
29.99
```

Comment: Can you share the XPath? @ArundeepChohan

Comment: Try something like //div[text()='Gross']/ancestor::div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[11]

Comment: You want to go up a couple of of divs then go to the second div then just div /div/div[11]

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I am not looking for directions to Dominos Outlet :) `You want to go up a couple of of divs then go to the second div then just div /div/div[11] – 
Arundeep Chohan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will do the job in one XPath without using random class-names:

```
//div[@class[contains(.,'d-flex')]]/div[count(//div[@class[contains(.,'justify-content-between')]][contains(.,'Gross')]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]/div
```

Comment: This one worked. I tried by changing the column position from 10th to 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are actually separated tables you can not do what you want by a single XPath expression.
What you do can is as following:
You can get the column number where `Gross` text is presented by this XPath:

```xml
column = count(//div[./div/div[text()='Gross']]/preceding-sibling::div[contains(@class,'fhvIWI'])+1
```

With current XML the `column` is 8
Now you can get the desired cells in the lower table with

```xml
//div[@class='sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI'][column]
```

The following expression

```xml
//div[@class='sc-cBNfnY fhvIWI'][8]
```

Gives the following results:

> 39.39
> 43.19
> 26.25
> 30.27
> 38.91
> 31.99
> 29.99

Comment: It looks good, just one question. Why are using width contains 7, because it could change depending on browsers and browser's resolution or some other factor.

Comment: I saw that. I used the width since I saw it as an unique attribute value distinguishing the relevant columns. Now I took a look again and found a unique class there, so now you can see really more reliable code. You can also combine the 2 XPath expressing to make it a single complex XPath of cause.

Comment: So, does my solution answers your question?

Comment: yes I got it  yes I got it  yes I got it